# Deny node has visible

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

When running the command `@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false)` all nodes (even those who are denied access) are displayed.

As an example I have the controller `Financeiro`

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Financeiro")]
public class homeController : baseController
{
    public ActionResult index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

In `Mvc.sitemap`

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Financeiro" roles="Financeiro" area="Financeiro" clickable="false">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Contas" controller="contas" action="index">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Nova conta" action="novo" changeFrequency="Never" btnClass="btn-primary"  />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Categorias" controller="categorias" action="index" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="A Pagar" controller="apagar" action="index" description="Contas a pagar" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="A Receber" controller="areceber" action="index" description="Contas a receber" />
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

## Ninject

I use Ninject, and installed package `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.DI.Ninject.Modules`

In file `MvcSiteMapProviderModule.cs`

```
this.Kernel.Bind<ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>().To<SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderStrategy>()
    .WithConstructorArgument("defaultProviderName", "MvcSiteMapProvider.FilteredSiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider, MvcSiteMapProvider");
```

## Packages

MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4        4.0.6
MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.Core   4.0.6
MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.DI.... 4.0.6
MvcSiteMapProvider.Web         4.0.6

**When a user (with or without `Financiero` role) accesses the system, the node is displayed**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you enable security trimming in your Ninject MvcSiteMapProviderModule.cs file? The default configuration has a variable at the top of the file.

```
bool securityTrimmingEnabled = false;
```

It is injected into the SiteMapBuilderSet near the end of the file:

```
// Configure the builder sets
this.Kernel.Bind<ISiteMapBuilderSet>().To<SiteMapBuilderSet>().Named("siteMapBuilderSet1")
    .WithConstructorArgument("instanceName", "default")
    .WithConstructorArgument("securityTrimmingEnabled", securityTrimmingEnabled)
    .WithConstructorArgument("enableLocalization", enableLocalization)
    .WithConstructorArgument("siteMapBuilder", this.Kernel.Get<ISiteMapBuilder>("compositeSiteMapBuilder"))
    .WithConstructorArgument("cacheDetails", this.Kernel.Get<ICacheDetails>("cacheDetails1"));
```

You need to change this to `true` in order for the security features to function.

**About the Exception:**

One possible workaround is to disable the AuthorizeAttributeAclModule in your DI config, as it looks like you are only using the XmlRolesAclModule:

```
// Before
        // Configure Security
        this.Kernel.Bind<AuthorizeAttributeAclModule>().ToSelf();
        this.Kernel.Bind<XmlRolesAclModule>().ToSelf();
        this.Kernel.Bind<IAclModule>().To<CompositeAclModule>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("aclModules", 
                new IAclModule[] { 
                    this.Kernel.Get<AuthorizeAttributeAclModule>(), 
                    this.Kernel.Get<XmlRolesAclModule>() 
                });

// After
        // Configure Security
        this.Kernel.Bind<XmlRolesAclModule>().ToSelf();
        this.Kernel.Bind<IAclModule>().To<XmlRolesAclModule>();
```

But that is only side-stepping the problem, and you shouldn't do this if you are using the Authorize attribute or similar filters.

I have never seen a configuration that would cause AuthroizeAttributeAclModule to throw an exception before, I would really like to take a look at why this is happening. Can you build a demo and open an issue @ GitHub?

Comment: After making this change, I get [this error](http://snag.gy/rHIeY.jpg)  

My [Mvc.sitemap here](http://snippi.com/s/mlih2tf)

Comment: I use the `[Authorize]`, why shouldn't do this if I am using `[Authorize]`?
In tests I did, it worked!  

As for example, I'll create one, and open an issue. Thanks.

Comment: This is effectively removing the security trimming for the Authorize attribute. The error will be gone, but so will your security trimming on Authorize attributes.